# Restler : make a get request with security key in post parameter

Tags: php, post, get, restler

I would like to call a rest function of my api with the GET protocol but I didn't succeed to put the security key of restler as a post parameter.

example:

/index.php/myrestapi/method.json?name=test
post field : Array('key'=>'mykey')

```
$session = curl_init('<mydomainurl>/index.php/myrestapi/method.json?name=test');

// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('key'=>'mykey');

// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($session);
```

Myrestapi.php function:

```
protected function getMethod($name){
    return $name;
}
```

What is wrong?!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Kevin

Comment: worth to remember that, if you try to add a "POST" parameter, you're doing a POST request, not GET.

Answer (score 0):

security key should also be part of get parameter

```
<mydomainurl>/index.php/myrestapi/method.json?name=test&key=mykey
```

Then need to handle that with iAuthenticate.

For more details see e.g. Protected API of restler.